# Upgrade nuget package

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget-package, sendgrid

I am following a [microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset) and it requires me to install `SendGrid` from the package manager. When I try to install it I get the following error in my package manager

Install-Package : The 'System.Net.Http 4.0.0' package requires NuGet client version '3.0' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.12.0.817'.
At line:1 char:16

- install-package <<<<  sendgrid
- CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], NuGetVersionNotSatisfiedException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Nuget is already installed to its latest version, is there anything that can be done about this? Alternatively, Is there another way to do a code first email confirmation and password reset using individual accounts?

Comment: What version of VS are you using? What version of NuGet do you have installed, and how are you checking that?

Comment: VS2013 and I have Nuget package 2.12.0.817 installed

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:asp.net-mvc] you simply need to upgrade your version of Nuget.

Comment: I have upgraded my nuget to the most recent version. There are no more available!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In visual studio, goto Tools -> Extensions & Updates -> Updates.

Select Nuget and click Update.

[image]

*If no further updates are possible*, **you are required to upgrade Visual Studio**.